# posting to one twitter account from rails app

Tags: twitter, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an app where posts are made by different users.  How would the oauth/post to twitter process change if I wanted all of the user's posts to hit a single twitter account (the apps twitter feed)?

I do not need to get authorization from each user since it should already be authorized.  Is there anything unique here that I should be aware of in approaching this situation or is the twitter gem still the way to go?

I've read quite a bit on this and have a good feel for the gems to use, but am curious how to get this to work since all other examples are about having users post to their own feed.

Thanks!